# Why does subsetting a matrix remove row or column name information?

Tags: r

For an N*N matrix with N=2, only the maximum value is returned in the following example:

```
d2<-matrix(1:4,nrow=2,ncol=2)
rownames(d2)<-c("a","b")
colnames(d2)<-c("d","e")
which.max(d2[which(rownames(d2)!="a"),which(colnames(d2)=="d")])
#returns:
[1] 1
rownames(as.matrix(which.max(d2[which(rownames(d2)!="a"),which(colnames(d2)=="d")])))
#returns
NULL
```

But for any N>2 matrix it returns this:

```
d3<-matrix(1:9,nrow=3,ncol=3)
rownames(d3)<-c("a","b","c")
colnames(d3)<-c("d","e","f")
which.max(d3[which(rownames(d3)!="a"),which(colnames(d3)=="d")])
#returns:
c
2
rownames(as.matrix(which.max(d3[which(rownames(d3)!="a"),which(colnames(d3)=="d")])))
#returns
[1] "c"
```

Why?! This is very confusing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with `as.dist()` or distance matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...Took me a while on this one

It has to do with the fact that R is dropping  the redundant information natively. Someone who has more time on their hands may be able to provide a more complete answer. But that's the reason:

```
> d3[which(rownames(d3)!="a"),which(colnames(d3)=="d"), drop=FALSE]
  d
b 2
c 3
> d2[which(rownames(d2)!="a"),which(colnames(d2)=="d"), drop=FALSE]
  d
b 2
> d3[which(rownames(d3)!="a"),which(colnames(d3)=="d")]
b c 
2 3 
> d2[which(rownames(d2)!="a"),which(colnames(d2)=="d")]
[1] 2
> as.matrix(d2[which(rownames(d2)!="a"),which(colnames(d2)=="d")])
     [,1]
[1,]    2
> as.matrix(d3[which(rownames(d3)!="a"),which(colnames(d3)=="d")])
  [,1]
b    2
c    3
```

`?drop`

> Value
>
> If x is an object with a dim attribute (e.g., a matrix or array), then drop returns an object like x, but with any extents of length one removed. **Any accompanying dimnames attribute is adjusted and returned with x: if the result is a vector the names are taken from the dimnames (if any). If the result is a length-one vector, the names are taken from the first dimension with a dimname.** Array subsetting (`[`) performs this reduction unless used with drop = FALSE, but sometimes it is useful to invoke drop directly.

Comment: I agree with you, that the drop flag should be a bit more prominent in the R documentation, or tutorials.  It should be noted, the actual behavior in R is more consistent with mathematical literature, where the name row or column vector is only useful in describing an embedded array.  Vectors as mathematical objects, only have length.  I would also like to make the comment that it is unnecessary to use which to subset by column or row name, just use the column or row name.

Comment: Thanks Alex and thanks @Jonathan, this cleared things up indeed!